# Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu doesn't free memory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, out-of-memory

I have a piece of code (Python 3.7) in a Jupyter notebook cell that generates a pandas data frame (df) containing numpy arrays.

I am checking the memory consumption of the df just by looking at the system monitor app preinstalled in Ubuntu.

The problem is that if I run the cell a second time, the memory consumption double even if the df is assigned to the same variable.

If I run multiple times the same cell, the system goes out of memory, and the kernel will dye by itself.

Using `del df` or `gc.collect()` won't free the memory as well.

Restarting the notebook kernel is the only way to free the memory.

In practice, **I would expect the memory to stay roughly the same because I am just reassigning a new df to the same variable over and over again.**

Indeed, the memory accumulates only if I run the code on  a linux machine and in the notebook. If I run the same code via terminal `python script.py`, or if I run the very same notebook on macOS, the memory pressure will not change, I can run the same cell multiple time and the occupied memory stays stable (as expected).

Can you help me pointing out where is the problem coming from and how to solve it?

P.S. Both Python and Jupiter are installed with Anaconda 2018.12 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have asked the same question on the Ubuntu community since I am not sure this is strictly related to python itself, but I got no answers so far.